# get String after specific text

Tags: java, string, substring

Get the String in bold between TEST: **["1","2"]**. i want to get the part of a string from [ to ]. The problem is i have multiple open and closed brackets like:
State:["VA","PA"],TEST: **["1","2"]**,City:["NYC"].

But i am only interested to get the string after TEST: . Can any one please suggest how can i extract that.

Thanks in advance.

For Example:

```
State:["VA","PA"],TEST: ["1","2"],City:["NYC"]
```

from above i just want to get ["1","2"]

```
State:["VA","PA"],Country:["US"],TEST: ["1","2"],City:["NYC"].
```

similarly i just want to get ["1","2"] which is after TEST: and from open bracket to closed bracket.

Comment: It seems to be `JSON` string. right ?

Comment: Its a JsonString converted to a normal String. @Ravi

Comment: So, what API are you using ?

Comment: This is a JSon converted to a string and saved in an application. Again we are retrieving this values as string directly from  that application.

Comment: yes, but what API are you using to convert and read ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regex, e.g.:

```
String src = "State:[\"VA\",\"PA\"],TEST: [\"1\",\"2\"],City:[\"NYC\"]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("TEST: \\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```